# swift - Terminating app due to uncaught exception '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

Tags: swift, database, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
@IBAction func NextButton(_ sender: Any) {


    //self.nextButton.isEnabled = false


        if emailTF.text != "" && passwordTF.text != "" {


            AuthProvider.Instance.registerButton(withEmail: emailTF.text!, password: passwordTF.text!, loginHandler: { (message) in

                if message != nil {
                    self.alertTheUser(title:"Problem With Authentication", message: message!);

                    self.nextButton.isEnabled = true


                } else {



                    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

                    let userEmail = self.emailTF.text!
                    let userPassword = self.passwordTF.text!



                    //self.ref.child("UserEmails").child(userEmail).setValue(["UID": userID, "Email": userEmail,"Password": userPassword])


// app does not crash when I run the below reference to database.


                    self.ref.child("Users").child(userID!).setValue(["UID": userID,"Email":userEmail,"Password": userPassword])

// app crashes when I run the below reference to database.

                    self.ref.child("Email").child(userEmail).setValue(["UID": userID,"Email": userEmail,"Password": userPassword])

                    //self.nextButton.isEnabled = true


                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.to_Select_Account_Segue, sender: nil);
                                       }
```

App work fines when I run

```
// app does not crash when I run the below reference to database.
                        self.ref.child("Users").child(userID!).setValue(["UID": userID,"Email":userEmail,"Password": userPassword])
```

Though when I run this code it crashes?

```
// app crashes when I run the below reference to database.
                        self.ref.child("Email").child(userEmail).setValue(["UID": userID,"Email": userEmail,"Password": userPassword])
```

Comment: you should include also some explanations to your question, not only the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant create a child nodes in `Firebase database` with `@` symbol. Use `.childByAutoId` or `uid` instead.

You should create user node like this:

```
static var refToUsersNode = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "MainDataBase/users")

// MARK: - Create user after registration
static func create(with login: String) {
  let loggedInUser = self.getCurrentUser()
  let currentDate = Date()
  let newUser = UserItem(uid: loggedInUser.uid, email: loggedInUser.email!,
                         login: login, createdDate: String(describing: currentDate))

  // Create a child path with a key set to the uid underneath the "users" node
  let refToNewUser = refToUsersNode.child(loggedInUser.uid)
  refToNewUser.setValue(newUser.toAnyObject())
}

static func getCurrentUser() -> FIRUser {
  return (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser)!
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: there is no @ symbol in my code? @vlad pulichev   the difference is when i put child.("users").child.(userID!) it works though when i put child("users").child(userEmail it doesnt work , i would just like to know why in the simplest way possible

Comment: @benpalmer661 You have .child(userEmail)

Comment: so i can on use a string like "email" and not  code such as;    var email = email.text    and the user email as a child?

Comment: @benpalmer661 you can't have @ in .child. Email contents it

Comment: sorry though i still dont understand could you explain it another way,  you mean it must be a string or user.uid?

Comment: or i can't have the word email?

Comment: because the email text field would have ben@mail.com    mean it would contain an @    omg !!!!!

Comment: @benpalmer661 understood?:)